# Make an Amazon EC2 instance ask for sudoing password

Tags: 12.04, command-line, virtualization, cloud, amazon-ec2

I've launched an Amazon EC2 instance of Ubuntu Server 12.04 and it's all fine except, unlike with my local Ubuntu, the EC2 instance never asks for any passwords when I'm sudoing with the command line or become root. I tried

```
passwd
# asks for a new password, I supply one
sudo -i
# always makes me root right away
passwd
# asks for a new password, I supply one
passwd ubuntu
# asks for a new password, I supply one
```

(`ubuntu` is the default user the instance gets installed with.) So far, event after reboots, I haven't noticed any difference, it still never asks for any passwords.

It's not a biggie but I guess I've just used to how my local Ubuntu works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

EC2 does not have an easy way to provide you with a secure password for the `ubuntu` user, so the default is to allow passwordless `sudo` after you connect securely with the ssh private key.

If you add a password to the `ubuntu` user, you can require it for `sudo` by editing `/etc/sudoers.d/90-cloud-init-users` and changing:

```
ubuntu ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL
```

to:

```
ubuntu ALL=(ALL) ALL
```

This command does that edit for you (assuming an untouched, default sudoers file):

```
sudo perl -pi -e 's%NOPASSWD:%%' /etc/sudoers.d/90-cloud-init-users
```

For safety, keep a separate shell logged in as root so that you can fix the file and recover if you edit it incorrectly and break `sudo`.

Adding a password for `sudo` increases the overall security of your system.

It is still recommended that you not allow the use of a password for ssh logins.  Keep that limited to ssh private keys.

Comment: If you use `sed` you won't have to install `perl`. Try `sudo sed -re 's/NOPASSWD://' -i.\`date -Iseconds\` /etc/sudoers.d/90-cloud-init-users` (this will make a backup file as well).